# Get next search result with key short cut

Tags: delphi

Trying to quick search in `Delphi 11` with keyboard short cut. I do `ctrl + F`, enter text and press `enter`. After this combination I have first search result.

I can get search next or previous search result by pushing arrow buttons in search menu, but how to do the same with key shortcut?

[image]

Comment: Didn't you like the solution you got a month ago? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74292522/search-down-and-search-up-short-key#comment131163300_74292522

Comment: It's even in [the documentation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Find).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press <kbd>F3</kbd> to continue to search, see [the docs](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Find).

Comment: Ctrl-L does the same thing.